# latest version of rdflib (4.0...) is not available for canopy enthought

Tags: enthought, canopy, rdflib

I have to work with rdflib 4.0.1 (the latest version of it) to work with sparql, but this package is not available in the Package Manager of Canopy (Enthought).

How can I install it, in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

The rdflib package is not in [the Canopy / EPD repository](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/).

Rather, it is in the "Community" (PyPi mirror) repo (marked by the "PyPI" logo in the Package Manager), which contains 11,000 untested ("as is") packages. Most of the packages are current and we are in the process of updating the rest, as well as keeping it updated from now on. Please note that we do not test for nor necessarily provide dependencies.

Meanwhile, this may help:
"[Installing external packages into Canopy Python](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-external-packages-into-Canopy-Python)"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in the "Community Pypi" is only available (at least in my Canopy 32b) rdflib 3.1.0-1 but I need the latest one (4.0.1).

Comment: The point is that the Community repo is a secondary priority, though improving gradually. Hence the link for how to install packages yourself if the Community repo doesn't meet your needs. See explication by lawlesst

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the link to installing external packages in Canopy that @jonathan-march provided, point three says to follow the "standard Python installation procedures."  It also includes information on installing [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/).  I would install pip using Canopy's instructions and then simply run `pip install rdflib`, which will install RDFLib 4.0.1.

> 1. To install a package which is not available in the Canopy / EPD repository, follow standard Python installation procedures from the OS command line. If you want to use pip, install it first:
>
>    `easy_install pip` (Please check this article for more info on using enpkg)